# Finding result against a `user_id` on the basis of two booleans laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a table `orders` from which I want to fetch data against a `user_id` on the basis of two booleans namely (`is_paid` and `is_cancelled`). The result will fetch me all orders of a `user_id` which are either `is_paid = true` or `is_cancelled = true`. Here is my query.

```
$query = orders::select('id','user_id','order_amount','created_date_and_time','order_address', 
                'is_cancelled','is_paid')
                ->Where('user_id', '=', $user_id)
                ->Where('is_paid', '=', true)
                ->orWhere('is_cancelled')
                ->get();
```

The query operates perfectly but it also gives me orders when I pass the `id` of a user who does not have orders in `is_paid` or `is_cancelled = true` state. The `orWhere` condition always gives results even if the `id` of a user with no orders is passed. Any help will really be appreciated TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your condition code change to raw sql will be

```sql
where user_id = ? and is_paid = true or is_cancelled = true
```

you need to change it to:

```sql
where user_id = ? and (is_paid = true or is_cancelled = true)
```

Use where closure:

```php
orders::select('id','user_id','order_amount','created_date_and_time','order_address', 
                'is_cancelled','is_paid')
                ->where('user_id', '=', $user_id)
                ->where(function($q) {
                     $q->where('is_paid', true)->orWhere('is_cancelled', true);
                })
                ->get();
```

Comment: Great thankyou for the help but there is a mistake in the ending orWhere of the query, $q->where('is_paid', true)->orWhere('is_cancelled'. true); the full stop i.e '.' after 'is_cancelled' should be a coma i.e ',' and it works perfectly then..please edit it so that i can mark your answer as correct. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The final query is being generated incorrectly. It checks

```
where user_id = $user_id and is_paid = true or is_cancelled = true
```

Existing conditon:

```
A && B || C
```

Required condition:

```
A && (B || C)
```

The corrected query is below.

```
$query = orders::select('id','user_id','order_amount','created_date_and_time',
                'order_address','is_cancelled','is_paid')
                ->where('user_id', $user_id)
                ->where(function($subQuery) {
                    $subQuery->where('is_paid', true)
                    ->orWhere('is_cancelled', true);
                })->get();
```